# Jetty, JAX-RS 2.1 and SSE

Tags: jersey-2.0, jetty-9

I tried to test Server-side events(SSE) on Jetty 9.4.7 but it doesn't work (but works on GlassFish 5). Here is my code:

```
@Path("sse")
public class SseResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
    @Path("time")
    public void currentTime(@Context SseEventSink eventSink, @Context Sse sse) {
        new Thread(() -> {
                OutboundSseEvent event = sse.newEventBuilder().name("current-time")
                        .data(String.class, LocalTime.now().toString()).build();
                eventSink.send(event);
        }).start();
    }   
}
```

When I try to call my endpoint /sse/time I get 404 exception:

javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: HTTP 404 Not Found
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:274) [jersey-server-2.26.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:272) [jersey-common-2.26.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:268) [jersey-common-2.26.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316) [jersey-common-2.26.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298) [jersey-common-2.26.jar:?]

Please, advise.

Answer (score 0):

I am very new to this , but this code and seems that work, with jax rs connector .

```
@Path( "events" )
public class ExampleService {

@GET
@Produces( SseFeature.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS )
 public EventOutput getServerSentEvents() {
  final EventOutput eventOutput = new EventOutput();
    new Thread( new Runnable() {

  @Override
  public void run() {
    try {
      for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
        Thread.sleep( 1000 );
        final OutboundEvent.Builder eventBuilder = new OutboundEvent.Builder();
        eventBuilder.name( "toevent" );
        eventBuilder.data( String.class, "Hello world " + i + "!");
        final OutboundEvent event = eventBuilder.build();
        eventOutput.write( event );
      }
    } catch( IOException e ) {
      throw new RuntimeException( "Error when writing the event.", e );
    } catch( InterruptedException e ) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      try {
        eventOutput.close();
      } catch( IOException ioClose ) {
        throw new RuntimeException( "Error when closing the event output.", ioClose );
      }
    }
  }
} ).start();
return eventOutput;
 }
 }
```

Comment: May a broadcaster also work,but i didn't manage to get it work.

Comment: Thank you. Did you test it with Jetty?

Comment: I test this code and run in jetty, but I use jax- rs connector from here : https://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2014/02/04/step-by-step-how-to-bring-jax-rs-and-osgi-together/

Answer (score 0):

The JAX-RS 2.1 follows the Java EE 8 specification. Latest Jetty 9.4.x follows Java EE 7 specification. So, you will need to wait for Jetty 10 which will have support for EE 8 . But it does not have any release date.

That said, Jetty does support SSE with JAX-RS 2.0